# Error at the last delete[]

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I couldn't understand why there is an error at `delete[] *iopszString;`,
can you help me fix it?

try the input: `1 3 aaa`

If I omit the last delete[] it all works but it doesn't make sense because
in order to exchange pointers I need to delete the previous point.
[The code](http://pastebin.com/wt182TLs)

```
// Notepad.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Method definition
void addText(char** iopszString);

void main()
{

    // Const definition
    int const ADD    = 1;
    int const UPDATE = 2;
    int const DELETE = 3;
    int const SAVE   = 4;
    int const EXIT   = 5;

    // Variable definition
    int nUserCode;

    // Code section

    // Gets the user code
    cout << "Enter the code: " << endl;
    cin >> nUserCode;

    // + "\0" so 1 minimum!!!
    char* iopszString = new char[1];
    iopszString = "";

    // Runs until the exit code
    while (nUserCode != EXIT)
    {
        // Checks the exit code
        switch (nUserCode)
        {
            case ADD:
            {
                addText(&iopszString);
                cout << iopszString << endl;
                break;
            }
            case UPDATE:
            {

                break;
            }
            case DELETE:
            {

                break;
            }
            case SAVE:
            {

                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                cout << "Wrong code, try again" << endl;

                break;
            }
        }

        // Gets the user code
        cout << "Enter the code: " << endl;
        cin >> nUserCode;
    }

    // Delete the string cuz heap
    delete[] iopszString;
}

void addText(char** iopszString)
{
    // Variables definition
    int  nAddLength;

    // Code section

    // Gets the new length
    cout << "Enter the length of the added string: " << endl;
    cin >> nAddLength;

    // Always remember - the length you want+1!!
    char* szNewString = new char[nAddLength+1];

    // Gets the new string
    cout << "Enter the new string which you want to add: " << endl;
    cin >> szNewString;

    // Creating a new string (result)
    char* szResult = new char[nAddLength+1+strlen(*iopszString)];

    // Copies the old string to the new
    strcpy(szResult, *iopszString);
    strcat(szResult, szNewString);

    // Deletes the new string cuz we already copied
    delete[] szNewString;

    // Exchange pointers 
    //strcpy(*iopszString, szResult); <--- never

    // The problem!
    delete[] *iopszString;

    // Exchange pointer 
    *iopszString = szResult;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I strongly recommend you start using `std::string` and stop using `void main`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is in these two lines:

```
char* iopszString = new char[1];
iopszString = "";
```

You are allocating new memory with `new` and you store its location in your pointer `iopszString`. You then assign the location of the string literal `""` to that pointer, so the value of the pointer itself changes. It now points somewhere else, to a memory location that you haven't allocated with `new` and that you don't own. You therefore lost the pointer of the memory you allocated (a memory leak) and when you call `delete[]` on the pointer to the location of `""`, it crashes (as you can not free anything with `delete[]` that you haven't allocated with `new`.

You probably meant to write:

```
char* iopszString = new char[1];
iopszString[0] = '\0';
```

Which will only set the value of the first `char` that you allocated to `'\0'` and therefore turns it into a valid, empty, zero-terminated string.

Comment: It solved the problem, thanks!
But can you please simplify the explanation?

Comment: @desmondmiles I tried to improve the explanation, hope it helps.